# Is there a way to force the rate using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate?

Tags: java, executorservice

When using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate, successive executions of task do not overlap.

> While different executions may be performed by different threads, the effects of prior executions *happen-before* those of subsequent ones.

So if the task execute longer than the period, the period is not guaranteed. Is there a best way to guarantee the period?

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement was to run a task as background task and does not care about the result, then

1. create a `Runnable` that will create a `Thread` and `start()` inline
2. submit the `Runnable`

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("Started ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }).start();
        };
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```